# r dynamically remove NA rows from data frame and record which field was NA

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have a data frame with 68 columns. I would like to dynamically check for invalid data based on a vector of variable names ordered by priority. If any of the set fields are NA I want those rows moved to a new data frame that would have an additional column containing the exclusion reason.

example data frame (with only 5 columns):

```
df1=data.frame(id=c(1:6),
   dob=as.Date(c("1/1/2001","2/2/2002",NA,"3/3/2003","1/1/1999",NA),"%m/%d/%Y"),
   sex=c("F","F","M",NA,NA,"M"),
   race=c("HA","HA","W","AA",NA,NA),
   survey=c("1",NA,NA,NA,"1","0"))
```

I want to be able to define `required_cols` dynamically. If `required_cols` was:

```
required_cols<-c("sex","race")
```

I would want to move all rows from `df1` that had NA for sex and race into an output table that would look like this:

```
 id dob        sex  race survey reason
 4  2003-03-03 <NA>   AA   <NA> sex
 5  1999-01-01 <NA> <NA>      1 sex
 6       <NA>    M  <NA>      0 race
```

AND update the original table to look like this:

```
  id dob          sex race survey
  1  2001-01-01   F   HA      1
  2  2002-02-02   F   HA   <NA>
  3       <NA>    M   W    <NA>
```

If the required_cols were `required_cols<-c("sex","survey")` I would want the output table to be:

```
  id        dob  sex race survey reason
2  2 2002-02-02    F   HA   <NA> survey
3  3       <NA>    M    W   <NA> survey
4  4 2003-03-03 <NA>   AA   <NA> survey
5  5 1999-01-01 <NA> <NA>      1 sex
```

and the original table to be:

```
  id        dob sex race survey
1  1 2001-01-01   F   HA      1
6  6       <NA>   M <NA>      0
```

I am able to get the original table updated using `complete.cases` but could use some guidance as to how to programatically move the unused cases into a new table and tag with the "reason" code.

Thanks in advance! I am new to R and stackoverflow so if you have advice on how to improve my question please lmk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` row-wise to find if any entries has `NA`, then remove (or subset) that row:

```
required_cols<-c("sex","race")
df1_with_NA<-df1[apply(is.na(df1[,required_cols]),1,any),]
df1_without_NA<-df1[!apply(is.na(df1[,required_cols]),1,any),]
df1_with_NA$reason<-lapply(
      apply(is.na(df1_with_NA[,required_cols]),1,function(x){
       required_cols[which(x)] }),paste,collapse=",")
```

Check output:

```
> df1_with_NA
  id        dob  sex race survey   reason
4  4 2003-03-03 <NA>   AA   <NA>      sex
5  5 1999-01-01 <NA> <NA>      1 sex,race
6  6       <NA>    M <NA>      0     race

> df1_without_NA
  id        dob sex race survey
1  1 2001-01-01   F   HA      1
2  2 2002-02-02   F   HA   <NA>
3  3       <NA>   M    W   <NA>
```

You can update the original table if needed `df1<-df1_without_NA`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to for loop through the data frame and using a chained if statement to identify what rows are NA using `is.na()`.

```
df1=data.frame(id=c(1:6),
               dob=as.Date(c("1/1/2001","2/2/2002",NA,"3/3/2003","1/1/1999",NA),"%m/%d/%Y"),
               sex=c("F","F","M",NA,NA,"M"),
               race=c("HA","HA","W","AA",NA,NA),
               survey=c("1",NA,NA,NA,"1","0"))

for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(is.na(df1$sex[i]) == T & is.na(df1$race[i]) == T){
    df1$reason[i] = 'sex & race'
  }else if( is.na(df1$sex[i]) == T){
    df1$reason[i] = 'sex'
  }else if( is.na(df1$race[i]) == T){
    df1$reason[i] = 'race'
  }else{
    df1$reason[i] = NA
  }
}
df1
# then subset the new df1 where reason is not NA to get the deleted rows
df2 = subset(df1, df1$reason == NA)
```

This is sort of a brute force method, but it works

```
 id        dob  sex race survey     reason
1  1 2001-01-01    F   HA      1       <NA>
2  2 2002-02-02    F   HA   <NA>       <NA>
3  3       <NA>    M    W   <NA>       <NA>
4  4 2003-03-03 <NA>   AA   <NA>        sex
5  5 1999-01-01 <NA> <NA>      1 sex & race
6  6       <NA>    M <NA>      0       race
```

Comment: thanks @cgage. There are many observations so i'm concerned about performance of a for loop.

Comment: No problem! Yea this method is definitely slower, @fishtank provided a much more efficient answer.